# The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-6, webactivator

I'm trying to run an ASP MVC 4 application on IIS. When I publish MVC 4 application from Basic template - without any dependencies apart from these made by the wizard - application works. But when I publish other application, that is using WebActivator and many other libs, I see this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

And complete stack trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +180
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +192
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +115
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +426
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) +64
>      WebActivator.AssemblyExtensions.GetActivationAttributes(Assembly assembly) +113
>      WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods() +216
>      WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods() +28
>      WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047).]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +423
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +591
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8946484 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +258

Is is IIS6 related issue, or I'm missing something on the server?